# How to pick best combinations of three columns and apply function by group using data.table in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `dt`

```
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(expand.grid(c("a","b"),1:2,1:2,c("M","N","O","P","Q")))
dt$perf <- rnorm(nrow(dt),0,.01)
colnames(dt) <- c("ticker","par1","par2","row_names","perf")
```

I want to pick the best combinations of `ticker,par1,par2` that will maximize the cumulative product over `row_names`. For example the following code does this but is not efficient in a `data.table` manner which I need it to be:

```
x <- split(dt,list(dt$ticker,dt$par1,dt$par2))
combn <- setDT(expand.grid(seq(1,length(x),2),seq(2,length(x),2)))
res <- data.table()

for(i in 1:nrow(combn)){
  tmp <- rbindlist(x[as.numeric(combn[i])])
  tmp <- tmp[,list(perf=mean(perf),par1=paste(par1,collapse=","),
                   par2=paste(par2,collapse=",")),by=row_names]
  cumRet <- c(cumRet,tail(cumprod(tmp$perf+1)-1,1))
  res <- rbind(res,data.table(cumRet=cumRet,
                              comb1 = names(x)[as.numeric(combn[i])][1], 
                              comb2=names(x)[as.numeric(combn[i])][2]))
}

res[which.max(cumRet)]
       cumRet comb1 comb2
1: 0.02452314 a.2.2 b.1.1
```

I know the following code does something similar in a `data.table` manner. However, it maximizes the combination per period without regard to keeping the `ticker,par1,par2` the same across `row_names M,N,O,P,Q`. I am looking for a solution similar to this but with the logic of my above implementation.

```
# best possible return
tmp1 <- dt[,list(par1=par1[which.max(perf)],
                par2=par2[which.max(perf)],perf=max(perf)),by=list(ticker,row_names)]
res1 <- tmp1[,list(perf=mean(perf),comb1= paste(c(rbind(par1,par2))[1:.N],collapse="."),
                   comb2=paste(c(rbind(par1,par2))[-1:-.N],collapse=".")),
                    by=row_names]
   row_names        perf comb1 comb2
1:         M 0.010413549   2.2   2.1
2:         N 0.009508122   2.1   2.1
3:         O 0.009314068   1.2   1.1
4:         P 0.008883106   2.2   1.2
5:         Q 0.009316006   2.2   2.2
tail(cumprod(res1$perf+1)-1,1)
[1] 0.0483428
```

Here is another way of doing this, but it still isn't exactly what I need:

```
# individual way
 tmp2 <- dt[,list(perf=tail(cumprod(perf+1)-1,1)),by=list(ticker,par1,par2)]
 tmp2 <- tmp2[,list(perf=max(perf),par1=par1[which.max(perf)],
                                      par2=par2[which.max(perf)]),by=ticker]
> tmp2
   ticker        perf par1 par2
1:      a 0.042091594    2    2
2:      b 0.007095708    1    1
> mean(tmp2$perf)
[1] 0.02459365
```

The result is very similar to my actual calculation `res`. It gives the correct combinations `a.2.2` and `b.1.1`. But the calculation of the average `perf` is wrong because averaging then taking the cumulative product is different than taking the cumulative product and averaging.

[image]I need a solution for the former whereas this finds the solution to the latter (it is not always the case that they will be this close or have the same combinations).

Lastly, here is yet another way of doing this but not quite exactly what I need. Below I try the combinations of `par1,par2` that maximize my result. Here, however, I use the same `par1,par2` on both `tickers`. I would like to apply the same `par1,par2` across `row_names` but allow different `tickers` to use varying combinations.

```
# group way
tmp3 <- dt[,.(perf=mean(perf)),by=.(par1,par2,row_names)]
res3 <- tmp3[,.(perf=tail(cumprod(perf+1)-1,1)),by=.(par1,par2)]
res3[which.max(perf)]
> res3[which.max(perf)]
   par1 par2       perf
1:    2    2 0.01756057
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a more `data.table` approach!

```
dt[,id:= paste(ticker,par1,par2,sep=".")]
setkey(dt,id)
combn <- unique(setDT(expand.grid(unique(dt$id)[1:length(unique(dt$id))/2],
                                 unique(dt$id)[(length(unique(dt$id))/2+1):length(unique(dt$id))])))

f1 <- function(x){

  return(tail(cumprod(dt[x,.(row_names,perf),by=.EACHI]
                      [,.(perf=mean(perf)),by=row_names]$perf+1)-1,1))
}

combn[,perf:=apply(combn,1,f1)]
combn[which.max(perf)]
    Var1  Var2       perf
1: a.2.2 b.1.1 0.02452314
```

I am not sure how to go through the `combn` combinations and apply the `data.table` approach that `f1` uses to make it a full `data.table` approach. But I believe that will make it as fast as possible!

**EDIT** Here is a almost fully complete `data.table` approach!

```
# create new dt that has all combinations and data
res2 <- rbindlist(lapply(1:nrow(combn),function(i) 
                    dt[as.matrix(combn[i])[1,],.(row_names,perf,comb=.GRP*i)]))
res2 <- res2[,.(perf=mean(perf)),by=.(row_names,comb)]
res2 <- res2[,.(perf=tail(cumprod(perf+1)-1,1)),by=comb]
res2[which.max(perf)]
   comb       perf
1:    4 0.02452314
> combn[4]
        Var1  Var2
    1: a.2.2 b.1.1
```